# Android JUnit mock Activity context

Tags: android, junit, android-testing

I have a method that I want to test. It has a DatePickerDialog inside which requires a context (Activity Context). I tried to use this

```
ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext<Context>()
```

But obviously, it doesn't work

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread Thread[Instr: androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner,5,main] that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

I need that DatePickerDialog only for one reason. To test that minDate and maxDate are set. Is it possible somehow to get a mock activity context?

Should I use the ActivityTestRule or ActivityScenario? Is there any other ways?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. Just added the [@UiThreadTest](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/annotation/UiThreadTest) annotation to my test method.